# Footer is not displaying properly on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

Website: ifnrussiacisforum.ru

It is 100% width on PC, but there's some empty space on mobile, likt this:
[image]

The code is:

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="images/logo-img.jpg" alt="beeboss" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .footer {
     height: 60px;
     width: 100%;
     background: #000;
  }

.footer .container {
    width: 1003px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

 .footer .container img {
     margin:19px 0px 0px 20px;
  }
```

Comment: have you tried width:100%

Comment: `width: 1003px;` is bad for responsiveness. I suggest using `100%` or at least `100vw`

Comment: Tried width:100% - still the same issue. Tried on two devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS code

CSS:

```
.footer .container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

 .footer .container img {
     margin:19px 0px 0px 20px;
  }
```

Comment: Tried width:100% - still the same issue. Tried on two devices.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with this code:

```
html, body {
    min-width: 1003px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#58fb912e2d456f902a77b8ebc76aa515

By default the body tag has a `margin`. You can fix that by either incorporating <kbd>[`Normalize`](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)</kbd> into your CSS or remove the `margin` in from your body.

**EDIT**: No wonder why your width was so grotesque you defined `800px` and `1003px` on most of your containers. Plus your CSS fairly very [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

Change the following classes `width` to `100%`

- .footer .container
- .main
- .header

Then replace min-width/change your width from `800px` && `1003px` to `80%` for the following classes.

- .extra-bally
- .request-form
- .link
- .plashka
- .bally
- .mac

Also focus on making your code more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

.footer .container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer .container img {
  margin: 19px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://forums.gota.io/images/smilies/smile.png" alt="beeboss" />
  </div>
</div>
```